# multi line parameter

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

```
[
{
"_id": "Some Comments.",
"Loan Name": "College Access",
"Description": "Some Comments.",
"Signer": "Some Comments.",
"Co-signer": "Some Comments.",
"Interest Rate": "0.0525",
"Deferment": "Some Comments."
}]
```

This is the json am using. I want to retrieve the `Loan Name` value in my project,But there is one space is present,If i give the Loan Name directly it through multi line marker problem.I dont know how to solve it .How can i access the value in java script .

Please any help to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what it means by **"multi line marker problem"**

Answer (score 1):

do it

```
 alert ( json[0]["Loan Name"]);
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7zS/)

Answer (score 1):

Array notation also works on JSON. Since you just have an array with one single record, no parent :

```
var test=[
{
"_id": "Some Comments.",
"Loan Name": "College Access",
"Description": "Some Comments.",
"Signer": "Some Comments.",
"Co-signer": "Some Comments.",
"Interest Rate": "0.0525",
"Deferment": "Some Comments."
}]

alert(test[0]['Loan Name']);
```

works